# Does enabling developer mode in ChromeOS disable automatic updates?

Tags: python, terminal, google-chrome-os

I want to enable full access to the terminal (to install Python), so I need to enable developer mode. But I don't want to lose automatic updates to ChromeOS.

Does enabling developer mode in ChromeOS disable automatic updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://youtu.be/4W87Tkb2mi0?t=4m29s

Direct from François Beaufort: automatic updates continue while in developer mode.

Answer (score 3):

No, developer mode does not disable automatic updates. My Chromebook has been in dev mode for over a year and I haven't missed an update yet.

Answer (score 2):

> The developer should be able to go back easily to running Google Chrome OS, at which point they should have access to automatic updates

[chromium os wiki](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/developer-mode#_Toc248215932_8072109296917915)

as for python [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python/nodpmmidbgeganfponihbgmfcoiibffi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher) give you a python shell fully usable

Answer (score 2):

I receive automatic canary updates every day in dev mode. That info must be outdated.